# How do I get a clean PWM (Modulation) signal to my RF supply/control for my laser?

Tags: digital-logic, digital-modulation

I connected a PWM signal to the MOD input for the RF power supply.  On the scope, it changed from a relatively clean signal to a very noisy signal.  The laser head did turn on and fire, however, the PWM generator controller started to show garbage on the LCD after about 30 seconds, and the RF supply started smoking.

I tried a second device that makes a PWM signal (0-10V).  After connecting to the RF supply/control, the high signal dropped to 1V.  There was no output from the laser and the RF supply was quiet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it smokes, you may want to make sure you didn't damage anything.  Anyway, it looks like the 4N38 chips are optoisolators with transistor outputs, the MOD pin drives the LED on one of them, and the RF pin is connected to the collector output of the other one.  I presume that output would indicate the status of the RF output, probably pulled low when it is turned on.

Comment: What are the allowed signals that can be fed into the device? Is it meant to have PWM as an input?